# Recieve constant updates from Google Drive API Android AppDataFolder?

Tags: java, android, google-api

I have created an Android application in which it is able to read files from the Google Drive Hidden AppData folder and react based on whether specific filenames are present.

I have created a separate external interface that creates a file in this folder and it seems to do it successfully.

The problem I have is that I can't seem to find a work around for having my android application constantly listening/receiving updates from the appdata folder.

The odd thing is, is that sometimes the application will pick up the file change straight away but other times it can take hours.

I'm convinced that Google's 'OnChangeSubscription' method they provide in the developer documentation doesn't actually work.

Any suggestions on methods I could try/where people have been successful at this would be great as I have been at it for weeks and it's the final thing I have left to do.

Comment: There is an exponential back off if you query too often in the Drive API - faced similar issue when i used it. I believe that the REST API doesn't have this issue - it's a bit more work to implement, but will get around the problem. Test for yourself in the oauth playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Cheers Mark, took a couple of hours to refactor but works perfectly!

Comment: No problem - a couple hours well spent though!